# window.onFocus intermittently doesn't fire on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onfocus

I'm trying to determine whether or not a tab is focused, for a chatroom app. I have:

```
window.onfocus = function () {
  isActive = true;
};
window.onblur = function () {
  isActive = false;
};
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and even in IE. But in Chrome, it only works intermittently; sometimes the event will fire, sometimes not. It will always fire if I click on a different window then click back to the Chrome window; but switching tabs doesn't always do it.

What can I do about this?

See live example here: http://holyworlds.org/new_hw/chat/onfocus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome\Windows, since Chrome on other platforms is unaffected.

Bug filed here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87812

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the rest of the script.

Try this

```
var isActive = true;
window.onfocus = function () {
  isActive = true;
    document.title = window.isActive;
};
window.onblur = function () {
  isActive = false;
    document.title = window.isActive;
};
```

Comment: Actually, I'd been using an interval to do that, because it was giving slightly better results. I've changed the example to your code anyway; same result. :P

Comment: Works for me in OSX 12.0.742.100 regardless of me loading a heavy page in another tab

Comment: Interesting... fails for me in Windows 12.0.742.100. This is starting to sound like a Chrome bug more than anything else.

Comment: It also works in Chrome Linux, so this is most probably a Chrome bug.